# How to use Google Agera with Retrofit 2

Tags: android, multithreading, retrofit, reactive-programming, retrofit2

I was considering to use RxJava for combining multiple retrofit calls and processing the results in a batch without much boilerplate code (*).

But RxJava added 4661 methods which did not let us stay under the dex limit. Google just introduced a "super lightweight Android library" (only 650 methods) as an alternative, called Agera. But Retrofit does not have built-in support for it so I'm wondering if anyone knows how to integrate the two.

(*) " to coordinate parallel threads, you’ll need to dip down into the more complex synchronization patterns using things like CountDownLatchs, Threads, Executors and Futures." - http://blog.stablekernel.com/replace-asynctask-asynctaskloader-rx-observable-rxjava-android-patterns/

Comment: Check out this tutorial: https://medium.com/@rezabigdeli6/agera-with-retrofit-69568ba4d1e1#.opy9le492

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a project on GitHub, [retrofit-agera-call-adapter](https://github.com/drakeet/retrofit-agera-call-adapter), that you can use (or be inspired by).